# Creating a TravisCI config for automated testing of a Go application

Tags: testing, go, travis-ci

I would like to create a .travis.yml  config that performes the following:

- fetches a Go application source code from Github,
- installs the other required libraries with `go get`
- attempts to build the go application with `go build`
- run tests with `go test`

I new to Go application testing with TravisCI, therefore I would appreciate any help or examples someone could point me to.

Comment: You probably should start here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a `.travis.yml` to the root of your repository;
2. Connect your GitHub account to TravisCI
3. Flick the switch to run builds on commits and pull requests.

Here's what I'm using for some of the Gorilla toolkit repos:

```
language: go
sudo: false

matrix:
  include:
    - go: 1.2
    - go: 1.3
    - go: 1.4
    - go: 1.5
    - go: 1.6
    - go: tip

install:
  - go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet

script:
  - go get -t -v ./...
  - diff -u <(echo -n) <(gofmt -d .)
  - go tool vet .
  - go test -v -race ./...
```

(source: https://github.com/gorilla/csrf/blob/master/.travis.yml)